# website to deploy in appEngine not showing

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

Hello: so I am trying to deploy a website to appEngine when I run it with the launcher the log does not have any errors, however when I go to local host the page is blank. I was running this website in python2.5 before with no issues, can you see any errors?

App.yaml

```
application: myappname
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|json|jpg|ico|js|css))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|json|jpg|ico|js|css))

- url: .*
  script: main.app

- url: /(.*\.json)
  mime_type: application/json
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.json)

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
```

main.py

```
import webapp2
import os
from google.appengine.ext.webapp2 import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp2 import template

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get (self, q):
    if q is None:
      q = 'index.html'
    path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
    self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/(.*html)?', MainPage)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the 3rd and 4th lines (you can combine them) to:

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util, template
```

That is, `webapp`, not `webapp2`.

Comment: Or, to use better-updated webapp2, use jinia2 for templating, as explained at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates